# Geolocation not responding in dreamweaver/phonegap for android

Tags: android, cordova, dreamweaver

I have a problem concerning the geolocation function in my android app and used the code below to test this default functionality (copied 1:1 from the phonegap website), but somehow can't get it to work.

When I build the android app the geolocation function does absolutely nothing, not an error, nothing. However when I test it in a browser everything works and a location is retrieved. All location services on the phone are turned on, when I turn them off, I do get the appropriate error message.

When I test the geolocation functionality in the phone's browser it does work.

I am testing on the Galaxy Nexus (android 4)
Dreamweaver CS 5.5 (updated today)
Latest Android sdk (updated today)
Manifest file is default, everything is permitted

Can somebody please help me out, I am starting to become really desperate as I can’t get this standard code to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                            'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                            'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                            'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                            'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                            'Timestamp: '          + new Date(position.timestamp)          + '<br />';
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After testing again on a galaxy s2 it does seem to work on android 2.3. Does anyone have any clue what could be the difference with android 4 regarding geolocation/phonegap? Again on the galaxy nexus all location services were enabled and do work in google maps and other geolocation test sites. Please help me out here!